# How to print backtick inside backticks

Tags: support

I tried to print

```
select * from `table`;
```

with some text on the same line. I wanted only the sql query to have the grey background.

I tried putting backtick around the query

```
`select * from `table``
```

Got something like this

some text `select * from`table`` some more text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use more than one backtick:

`` select * from `table`; `` in the same line as text

Source:

````
```select * from `table`;```
````

This also works for comments.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the first or last character is a backtick itself. For example, without that semicolon on the end, Markdown would fail to parse it at all.

Comment: @animuson If the last character is a backtick, you have to separate from the delimiter string, e.g. with a space: ```select * from `table` ```

Comment: I don't know about you, but a space on the end looks rather silly. I was just noting that there has to be *something* there.

Comment: When starting or ending with a backtick, add a space to *both* the opening and closing backtick(s) so that it doesn't actually display, user000001 and @animuson. See "Backticks within backticks" in the dupe.

Comment: @Arjan nice. Didn't know that.

Comment: Why don't they keep it simple and allow you to escape it with a backslash? Backslashes aren't shown regardless.

Comment: I ran into a problem with this inside a comment. I had added spaces between the triple-ticks and the content, and that doesn't work. At least in comments. At least with my content, which didn't end in a back-tick. Removing the spaces at the edges made it work.