# Escaping back-ticks works in comments, but not in answers?

Tags: support, markdown

I'm not exactly sure why this works as it does, but escaping backticks in comments with backslashes works, but not in answers.

For example, consider the following markdown:

```
`\`table\`.\`column\` AS \`other_column\``
```

In a comment, the above will render as `` `table`.`column` AS `other_column` `` but inside of an answer it renders as:

`\`table`.`column` AS `other_column``

---

I'm using the "triple back-tick" workaround from [this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254364/how-to-print-backtick-inside-backticks) to handle things now, but why is the markdown parsing different for comments versus answers?

Comment: **Proof** - It works just fine in comments: `\`table\`.\`column\` AS \`other_column\``

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Let's see what the [Markdown documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) has to say:

## Inline code spans

> To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters:
>
> ``` ``There is a literal backtick (`) here.`` ```
>
> which will produce this:
>
> `` <p><code>There is a literal backtick (`) here.</code></p> ``
>
> The backtick delimiters surrounding a code span may include spaces — one after the opening, one before the closing. This allows you to place literal backtick characters at the beginning or end of a code span:
>
> ``` A single backtick in a code span: `` ` `` ```
>
> ``` A backtick-delimited string in a code span: `` `foo` `` ```

In other words, the "triple backtick workaround" you mention isn't actually a workaround, it's the correct way to escape backticks in a code span. Note that you could also use double backticks and a space at the beginning and end of the span, as above.

## Backslash escapes

> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s formatting syntax. For example, if you wanted to surround a word with literal asterisks (instead of an HTML `<em>` tag), you can use backslashes before the asterisks, like this:
>
> `\*literal asterisks\*`

Keep in mind that inline code spans *already* treat their contents as literal characters (except for backticks, see above). This means that `` `\` `` is treated as a code span containing the single character `\`, *not* as the beginning of a code span containing a literal `` ` ``.

## Why is Markdown parsing different for comments vs. answers?

Comments only support a subset of Markdown syntax. This is addressed in the [FAQ on code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362):

> In comments, the additional space in the delimiters is not supported. Instead, escape the backtick: ``` `\`<html>\`` ``` and ``` `$\`` ``` to get `` `<html>` `` or `` $` `` in a comment.

I assume this is a feature unique to Stack Exchange's implementation of Markdown used in comments, since it's not mentioned in the [official Markdown documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Comment: I feel like once upon a time the multiple-backticks didn't work in comments, so maybe the backslash bit was added as a workaround.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that a single backslash and single backtick [work in comments, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/289905#comment1174312_3122): ``\``, `\``. Type: `\`\`\\`\`, \`\\`\``.

Answer (score 12):

Another proof...?

`\`table`.`column` AS `other_column``

Yeah, is bad...

Comment: You just wanted some points, go on admit it, didn't ya :) There ya go, have some :)

Comment: @webnoob:  They don't count on Meta, so I'm not sure what you're talking about...

Comment: -1. at ~1700 rep you should know better. this is not an answer it is a comment.

Comment: @self - I think he was just demonstrating the point that the OP was trying to make. You can't demonstrate that via a comment as the OP is specifically talking about it being broken in an answer.

Comment: @webnoob I thought that was the joke. I guess I prefer to assume good faith and jocularity, rather than someone being both rude and wrong.