# Comment with inline code that is just a backtick

Tags: support, comments, markdown

This is definitely a small edge case, but I haven't found a way to format as inline code `` ` `` in comments. The first comment on this question will demonstrate the problem (otherwise the question will be deleted).

Note that in a question (and I presume an answer), this isn't a problem. All you need to put the backtick in inline code is

```
`` ` ``
```

---

I did actually have a use case for this. My 5 minute edit window ended before I could find a solution to the problem - the comment in question is the second on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787727/understanding-haskell-function-type-constraints.

---

To potential duplicate voters: I know how to print a backtick inside backticks. This is a specific case in which that solution *does not work* specifically in a comment only.

Comment: This should be a backtick `` ` `` but it isn't. :(

Comment: Escape a back tick with a back slash inside two back ticks - `\`\\`\``, which gives `\``.

Comment: @MikeM. Nice find! That sounds like an answer, not just a comment though!

Comment: Hang on. Still playing in the sandbox.

Comment: @CodyGray: no, this is specifically about comments. Still a duplicate but I can't locate the original.

Comment: @RadLexus Perhaps you could still shed some light on why the problem happens?

Comment: @CodyGray No it doesn't try it. :) I did in the first comment

Comment: Alec, the comment box uses a slightly different Markdown parser than question/answer boxes (it's heavily dumbed-down). It's imaginable that either "correct" backtick processing was culled from the main branch, or, alternatively, it was corrected or added into the main branch but never into the comment parser.

Comment: Yep, @Cody's right. It's the very last thing in the answer there.

Comment: I don't think this should be a duplicate, because AFAICT the canonicals don't talk about comments at all, and they seem to follow different rules.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like this can be done by backslash escaping a back tick inside two other back ticks.

```
`\``
```

Comment: I would love to know _why_ this is. Why is the solution in my question invalid only invalid when in a comment!?

Comment: I don't know the details, but markdown apparently has some big differences between comments and posts. You should see the jumble I had to use to get `\`\\`\`` to show in a comment.

Comment: What worked for me was this answer (use more than one backtick) : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254366/2186074

Comment: This is a test `\`[\``. Nice (+1)!!

Comment: Can you simply quot "\"? I do reproduce `\`\\`\``, but quoting only the backslash seems impossible. `\`\\`` can't do that.  `\`\\\`` can't do that, too.

Comment: This is a test: `\``.

Comment: Testing... `Ctrl+\``

Comment: this is test `\``